# rspec - how to get test to pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, associations

```
  context "can have 2 companies associated with it(v2)" do
    it "should have an error when multiple companies can't belong to an industry " do
        @company1 = Factory(:company)
        @company2 = Factory(:company)
        @industry = Factory(:industry)
        @company1.industry = @industry
        @company2.industry = @industry
        @industry.should have(2).companies
    end
  end
```

This test is failing and I am having a hard time with it.
15 other tests are ok.
The problem is when I try to use related objects.

My models are:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :industry
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_length_of :state, :is => 2, :allow_blank => true
  validates_length_of :zip, :maximum => 30, :allow_blank => true
end
class Industry < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
  default_scope :order => "name asc"
end
```

Just inserting the records themselves does seem to work ok -

```
  context "can have 2 companies associated with it" do
    it "should have an error when multiple companies can't belong to an industry " do
      lambda do
        @company1 = Factory(:company)
        @company2 = Factory(:company)
        @industry = Factory(:industry)
        @company1.industry = @industry
        @company2.industry = @industry
      end.should change(Company, :count).by(2)
    end
  end
```

btw the top of my spec is:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe Industry do
  before(:each) do
    @industry = Factory(:industry)
  end
```

I have also commented out

```
#  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

at the bottom of `spec/spec_helper.rb` but that didn't help

Comment: Have you tried calling reload on industry before checking for companies associated with it? @industry.reload

Comment: I think you need to save the company objects after adding the industry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the company belongs to an industry, then when you create a company, it's creating the industry for each.

You're accounting for this by setting the industry to the companies, but you're not saving them. Alternatively, you can:

```
before do
  @industry = Factory(:industry)
  @company1 = Factory(:company, :industry => @industry)
  @company2 = Factory(:company, :industry => @industry)
end

it "should have both companies" do
  @industry.companies.should == [@company1, @company2]
end
```

Comment: awesome.  btw I can also use `@industry.companies.count.should == 2` 
at the end